# How to get/print Updated Time per second in a Tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to print current time in seconds on a label in a window using Tkinter, but instead of updating every 500 milliseconds it just remains the same.

Any ideas what I can do to get this thing right?

```
def timeout():
    t=time.time()
    window.after(500, timeout)
    return t

window = Tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Example")


time_label= Tkinter.Label(text=timeout(),
                    bg="black",fg="white").grid(row=1,column=2)        

window.geometry("100x100+100+100")
window.after(500, timeout)
window.mainloop()
```

Should I use something other than Label for this?

Comment: What is doing_it? So you want the clock to display only updated seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `label` will get the current time, then not do anything anymore. The `timeout` function will call `doing_it` after half a second, but I don't see that defined anywhere. Here's what you'll want to do:

```
def timeout():
    time_label.config(text=time.time())
    window.after(500, timeout)

window = Tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Example")


time_label= Tkinter.Label(text='',
                    bg="black",fg="white")
time_label.grid(row=1,column=2)        

timeout()
window.geometry("100x100+100+100")
window.mainloop()
```

This initializes the `label` to the empty string, then immediately calls `timeout`. That function configures the `label` to the current time, then queues up a call *to itself*. After the requisite time has passed, `Tkinter` will call `timeout`, which updates the `label` and queues up another call to itself. This will continue until you put a stop to it. If you want to do that, create a flag (such as `running=True`) and check for it before the call to `after()`. Then, when you set it to `False`, `timeout()` will stop telling `Tkinter` to call it.

Comment: I tried it your way but got an error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config' ; so copied it exactly and then ran it , still the same , can u please just check it once again , thanks .@TigerhawkT3

Comment: I didn't notice that you had combined your widget creation with its geometry management (e.g. `Label().grid()`). This is something you should avoid, because, as you saw, the reference then points to the returned value of `grid()` (or whatever manager you're using), which is `None`. I've edited the answer to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

**Read this One Carefully, Every Each and Every Code...**

```
from tkinter import *
import time


#defining TK()
root = Tk()


#defining Functions

def timesnow():
    currentime = time.strftime ("%H:%M:%S")
    timelabel.config (text=currentime)

    timelabel.after(1000, timesnow)


#creatng GUI's
timelabel = Label(root, font=("Courier", 44))
timelabel.grid()
timesnow()


input = Entry(root)
input.grid()

setbutton = Button(text = "Set Your ALARM")
setbutton.grid()




root.mainloop()
```